# Can I update a table by inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a table by inner join? I guess I'm missing something in my code; Am I doing correctly?

```
UPDATE a    
  SET product_name = "value2"   
  from tbl1 a
  INNER JOIN tbl2 b
    ON a.sid = s.id
   Having b.product_name="value1"
```

@Gordon: can the following query do the same as yours:

```
  UPDATE tbl1 a 
  INNER JOIN tbl2 b
  ON a.sid = s.id 
  SET product_name = 'value2' 
  having b.product_name = 'value1';
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: MYSQL; sorry just updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for MySQL is:

```
UPDATE tbl1 a INNER JOIN
       tbl2 b
       ON a.sid = s.id AND b.product_name = 'value1'
  SET product_name = 'value2' ;
```

EDIT (in response to comment):

Formally, you would only be allowed to use a `having` clause when you have an aggregation.  And, you cannot update aggregated queries in any dialect of SQL.

MySQL extends the `having` clause so it behaves a lot like a `where` clause when there is no `group by` clause.  Actually, the `having` clause is extended so it can use column aliases defined in the `select` statement (which is not applicable in an `update` query).

Your query with the `having` clause doesn't actually work in MySQL, because the extension is for the `select, but not the`update`.  Replace it with a`where`statement or move the condition to the`on` clause.

Comment: Could you please see my updated question? I want to make sure whether my query with "having" does the same thing

Comment: @user3000457, please read about the having clause. You'll see your query is totally inadequate, and on top of that does not even compile.